# css loader not working

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-loader

I'm trying to import a carousel into my project and no matter which one I use I get errors saying `you may need an appropriate loader` pointing at the carousels css file

```
  {
    test: /\.s?css$/,
    include: [/src/],
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
      fallback: 'style-loader',
      use: ['css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader'],
    }),
  },
```

I am doing this so surely this should cover it right?

can post more code but error coming from here: `react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css:1`

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`

Comment: Paste your package.json file

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `loader:'style!css!'`

```
  {
    test: /\.s?css$/,
    include: [/src/],
    loader:'style!css!',
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
      fallback: 'style-loader',
      use: ['css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader'],
    }),
  },
```

**Attempt 2**

Try updating test to `test: /\.css$/,` (long shot)

```
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    include: [/src/],
    loader:'style!css!',
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
      fallback: 'style-loader',
      use: ['css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader'],
    }),
  },
```

**Attempt 3**

Try setting loaders this way

```
loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
```

or

```
loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
```

Comment: made no difference unfortunately :(

Comment: ok, that was the only reference I saw to the error you made.... https://github.com/shama/letswritecode/issues/8

Comment: Added a couple other things to try

Answer (score 0):

Do this if you want to add multiple loaders

Install the modules like this `npm install --save-dev css-loader`

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
       fallback: "style-loader",
       use: [
           {
              loader: 'css-loader'
           },
           {
              loader: 'postcss-loader'
           }
           // more loaders if you have any
           // Make sure you installed this loaders
        ]
    })
}
```

Give this a try any let me know if any issues.

Reference [here](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/)

Comment: missing a comma between use objects

Comment: still same issue unfortunately :(. it's  still pointing at the first line of the css file inside the node module

Comment: Make sure the modules are installed

Comment: On which line you are getting this error @TheWalrus SyntaxError: Unexpected token .?

Comment: @RaajNadar here: `workspace/project/node_modules/react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css:1`

Answer (score 0):

> Make sure you updated your **include** to include **/node_mobuldes**

Also if that doesn't work try separating your css and sass loader.

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  include: [/node_modules/, /src/],
  use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    fallback: 'style-loader',
    use: ['css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader'],
  }),
},
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  include: [/src/],
  use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    fallback: 'style-loader',
    use: ['css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader'],
  }),
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try importing the carousel css in your css/scss file like this

```
@import "~react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css";
```

then in your webpack file try this setting

```
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
      fallback: 'style-loader',
      use: 'css-loader!postcss-loader',
    }),
  };
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
      fallback: 'style-loader',
      use: 'css-loader!postcss-loader!sass-loader',
    }),
  };
```